# Using a static logger to print elements is creating multiple files with same content?

Tags: java, static

I used a logger to see an element's value, now i can see my application takes more time to start and when i see the log the file that was intended was created more than 100 times.

The elements are printed in every file? What is causing this behavior?

Is there something if we use static variable and that variable is used by many method's in application then for each method one file is created!! But i know the static variable as a single value used for all the accessing objects??

The declaration of logger is

```
 private static Logger telog = Logger.getLogger(XMLCIMHandler.class.getName());
        FileHandler fh;
```

and initialization is

```
try {
                File file = new File("C:\\TElogs");
                boolean b = file.mkdir();
                fh = new FileHandler("C:\\TElogs\\TElogs%u.%g.log",
                        1000000, 10);
                      telog.addHandler(fh);
                telog.setUseParentHandlers(false);
                SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
                fh.setFormatter(formatter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
                e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                String s = writer.toString();
                telog.info("  "+ s);
            }
```

and to print elements i used `TElog.info(element);`
Please explain... Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have some code (and logger configuration) to share?

Comment: @Thilo Thank You... I updated it in question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely because you initialize the logger in the constructor. This would mean that each instance of the class would create a new file.

You need to either initialize it in the [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), or check if it is already initialized before you initialize it.

Comment: or, if possible with a configuration file, don't initialize it in code at all

Comment: Yes, that was the problem actually. Now i initialize it in a separate method then i am getting logs in Java console. Could you please suggest how to get these logs in the desired files ? Thanks a lot.